# How to choose font different font-weight? use bolder one or just font-weight?

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, typography, font-family

[Before we start] I'm a Chinese user, and there are so many different weights of Chinese font. They are in the same font-family, but they didn't stay together like latin fonts, e.g., Huakang Chaohei(~Black) and Huakang Cuhei(~Bold).For that, I have to choose different font-family, rather than font-weight.

So this question happens so frequently to me when choosing different font-weight and font-family.

---

Just like the following picture, can I use `font-family: "helvetica bold"` in CSS? Or, use `font-family: helvetica; font-weight: 600` to specify the bolder version of helvetica?

[image: font-family example of helvetica(regular, light, bold)]

UPDATE:

Thanks all. So how to do with the name different than bold?

[image: font-family of tahoma]

Comment: "family: helvetica; font-weight: 700" is the right way to do it. "helvetica bold" does not exist as a font. The value 700 equals bold by the way. [Read more here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the latter,  like this:

```
font-family: helvetica; 
font-weight: bold;
```

or you can use this:

```
  font-weight: bold;
```

Note, you likely should include more fonts, as not all browsers will render helvetica, so you could use something like this:

```
font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
```

**Edit to match the above edit:**

he values you can use are `normal` (which is the default weight), `bold`, `bolder`, `lighter`. You can also use the values from 100 to 900, the higher being bolder. You can also use `initial` and `inherit`.

Note font-weight should work fine with Chinese;  the fonts themselves are the ones you need to pay attention to.

Comment: Thanks, it did help. And, I wonder how to deal with other font-weight name different from *bold*.

Comment: Here is the official documentation  http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/font-weight

Comment: Here's some reference for Chinese fonts:  http://www.kendraschaefer.com/2012/06/chinese-standard-web-fonts-the-ultimate-guide-to-css-font-family-declarations-for-web-design-in-simplified-chinese/